# Best air conditioner for cold blasts?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

The old air conditioners I had could blow out snow literally that is how cold they got, now air conditions are only moderately cold. What would be the best system to get to just blast one giant vent of snowy air into a living room? For example buying a full size central ac system but only hooking it to one large vent or do I just want an overpowering mini split?

Specifically I am looking to blow a large quantity of ice cold air onto myself in a 500 sqft room and have it get to almost freezing temperatures.

Comment: get a walk-in freezer

Comment: Why would you want this?

Comment: @Harper I used to have an old window air condition that would blow out snow and my room would get to 40 degrees and it was fun, now you have central AC systems that can hardly make it cold... I like freezing temperatures.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how better to contribute here. (That said, I'm guessing that cooling to just what you need is more efficient.)

Answer (score 2):

The change is we are regulated in some cities and or states to energy star requirements, if I put in a massive system I can get in trouble, not true in all areas but this may be why. Can you have a split added to make 1 room a “freezer” sure. 
Call your local HVAC company and tell them you want a split in your room that you want cold, tell them you have poor insulation and how many square feet and the number and size of the windows, and ask what is the size unit needed to really cool this room down (some controllers are limited to 68f) and let them know what your desired temp is for this room, if they can do it they would love the work, that or you get a massive window unit and put some insulation on the temp probe. That’s kind of how I made a walk in cooler in my garage using a portable ac unit.

Comment: Re: Window unit with insulated temp probe—interesting idea and clever solution. Any chance of some pics of this walk-in cooler/garage space? My curiosity is peaked.

Comment: Sorry I don’t have it assembled right now , I put the walls up if slaughtering or hunting and want to hang the meat longer, it’s just rigid foam panels with a foam roof section 240v 24000 btu window unit I fixed up and shifted the temp probe and it works great.